# How do I download a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, download

I'm running Perl on Windows XP, and I need to download a file from the URL http://marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx.

How should I do this? I have attempted using WWW::Mechanize, but I can't get my head around it.

This is the code I used:

```
my $url = 'marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get($url);
```

Comment: Can you please post some code to show what you tried with WWW::Mechanize and indicate what didn't work as expected?

Comment: BTW, I see empty page on that URL

Comment: This is the code I used:
my $url = 'http://marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get($url);

Yeah it's actually an empty page which should download a .kmz file. You have to be persistent cause some times it doesn't download.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd use [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx';
my $file = 'data.kml';

getstore($url, $file);
```

Comment: I tried both LWP simple and WWW mechanize but I am getting Status Read failed : connection reset by peer. Url - http://27.251.47.106/BLal/Design/OPD/LabReport_Interface.aspx?TestID=LSHHI472&PID=LSHHI643736&LedgerTransactionNo=371411000582

Comment: Probably best to raise this as a new question.

Answer (score 22):

I used [File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html) as this is a core Perl module (I didn't need to install any additional packages) and will try a number of different ways to download a file depending on what's installed on the system.

```
use File::Fetch;
my $url = 'http://www.example.com/file.txt';
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $file = $ff->fetch() or die $ff->error;
```

Note that this module will in fact try to use LWP first if it is installed...

Comment: Using File::Fetch under `Linux 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (MythTV server), `$ff->fetch()` returns an error (nonzero) but `$ff->error(1)` produces no diagnostics.  `strace -f` shows no attempt to retrieve the specified file.  The `LWP::Simple` approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670489/5025060 does work.

Answer (score 5):

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx';
my $local_file_name = 'getkml.aspx';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

This in fact wraps around the `LWP::UserAgent->get`.

More details can be found at [WWW::Mechanize docs page](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Eget(_$uri_)).

Answer (score 4):

If downloading that file is all you actually do, you'd better go with @davorg's answer.

If this is part of a bigger process, you access the ressource you downloaded as a string using method [`content`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#CONTENT-HANDLING-METHODS)  on your `$mech` object.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone needs an oneliner ;)

```
perl -e 'use File::Fetch;my $url = "http://192.168.1.10/myFile.sh";my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);my $file = $ff->fetch() or die $ff->error;'
```

Just change the content of `$url`