# Get picture from website in perl

Tags: perl, file, save, uri, image

I'm looking for a good way to save pictures from website. I'm given the urls of picture. What is the standard way to save pictures in Perl? Considering saving them as string in array or .jpg file. (which one is better?) And also, I need the functionality to modify the file name. Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by saving pictures as a uri. A URI is just a string that identifies the picture (for example the URL).  It contains none of the picture information and isn't an alternative to jpg.

Comment: My bad. I thought URI means store picture in a string. Sorry that I confused you.

Comment: [How do I download a file using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669670/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I guess the standard way is the following: first, you grab the content of the remote picture, then save this content under the whatever name (and path) you like.

This can be done by several ways, the easiest, I suppose, is just use plain and simple CPAN module [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple):

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'here goes some url'; 
my $file = 'here goes a filename'; 

getstore($url, $file);
```

Well, that's it. ) Yep, that simple. Of course, it may probably be decorated with some error checks (and related messages), but for the simplest tasks that should be quite enough.

Or even better, it can be reduced to a one-liner:

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'getstore("http://google.com/", "~/have/grabbed/the.internets")'
```

Comment: I can't find MLWP any where. where do you get it?

Comment: -M option loads a module specified as its argument; the module name is the same - LWP::Simple.